# TypeScript: in recursive type, extra props allowed to be assigned in object declaration only

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

When creating an object using the following recursive type, somehow extra keys not present in the type are allowed to be added when the object is created (but not afterward). Any thoughts on why this is?

```js
type WithChildProps<Props, ChildProps> = Props & { __childProps__: ChildProps };

type WrappedProps<Props extends Record<string, any>, WrapperPropsTuple extends any[]> = WrapperPropsTuple extends [infer ParentProps, ...infer ChildProps]
  ? ChildProps extends []
    ? WithChildProps<ParentProps, Props>
    : WithChildProps<ParentProps, WrappedProps<Props, ChildProps>>
  : string;



type ObjTuple = [
  { prop1: string },
  { prop2: string },
  { prop3: string },
];

type ObjProps = { mainProp: string };

type ObjWrappedProps = WrappedProps<ObjProps, ObjTuple>;

const obj: ObjWrappedProps = {
  prop1: 'allowed',
  __childProps__: {
    prop2: 'allowed',
    __childProps__: {
      prop3: 'allowed',
      extraProp: 'why is this allowed?', // Should error but doesn't
      __childProps__: {
          mainProp: 'allowed',
          extraProp: 'and this also?', // Should error but doesn't
      },
    },
  },
};

// Errors as expected
obj.extraProp = 'expected error';
obj.__childProps__.__childProps__.extraProp = 'expected error';
```

Comment: It might be the bug at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44750 or something similar; hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm unable to explain this behavior, I can provide you with working utility type.

Consider this example:

```js
type ObjTuple = [
  { prop1: string },
  { prop2: string },
  { prop3: string },
];

type ObjProps = { mainProp: string };

type Key = '__childProps__';

type Builder<
  Tuple extends any[],
  Level extends number[] = [],
  Result = {}> =
  Level['length'] extends Tuple['length']
  ? Result & ObjProps
  : Tuple[Level['length']] & {
    [Prop in Key]:
    Builder<Tuple, [...Level, 1], Result>
  }


// ok
const test: Builder<ObjTuple> = {
  prop1: 'allowed',
  __childProps__: {
    prop2: 'allowed',
    __childProps__: {
      prop3: 'allowed',
      __childProps__: {
        mainProp: 'allowed',
      },
    },
  },
};

const test2: Builder<ObjTuple> = {
  prop1: 'allowed',
  __childProps__: {
    prop22: 'allowed', // expected error
    __childProps__: {
      prop3: 'allowed',
      __childProps__: {
        mainProp: 'allowed',
      },
    },
  },
};

const test3: Builder<ObjTuple> = {
  prop1: 'allowed',
  __childProps__: {
    prop2: 'allowed',
    __childProps__: {
      prop3: 'allowed',
      __childProps__: {
        mainProp2: 'allowed', // expected error
      },
    },
  },
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwCoFcwBtoF4oG0BQUUA3lGAE4D2YAjAFxQDOw5AlgHYDmUAvgDSESZKmABMDZmy68BRUhWoBmCSw7d%20%20ALoBufPlCRYiAAojGUHKQC2AQw6nqKqet37w0ANIQQFqAHIAfQCAYwALVnQAEwcwRiC-VwNoACEUCMiIcgAeQVQMaAgAD2AIdkjzG3YQXE1ZKAAZCAA3CHQoIpKy83YUKzhMmt8auoAlCEYUdGBfYh4APgtBRpb0XD9MLmBQv0124tLyqDzMNY3OLZ3BAH4oMYmpqAAyIwQYxkEGY4hcZdbT0vO200u2exEERFwMSgHCgXhAmjo4KgqXSmSyXz4eAAdDjfuhMTRardxpNgHNBDw9PgAPTUqCUADW%20GClHYzCgJWYDBRUTR8GQaEwC0sggUtAYfhs6HQlAA7hBIn46kEwuk3kEGGCiEQxeJ-FKZfLFXUiCrwlF1QFNUidSJlPrpXKFUqbVAzWqzBqSK6iLZ7CIJQancbXRptTIKQIeK4WWzppzgHqeRlsvyvsLvbbqPQHYbncqQubop6rZntbq9ZLHUalVBaXtIMESpF2uQqOQke6LSXreGs2B7VW8yG%2027Cx7qHFS1rR1A-ewYoHq-nQyaI0QNNG9LH2Qn7cm%20Yh0zNRSIc0Pgy7TePu5OvTP%205WgzW113i3fp66xYPnyvR2-LV7Wd5xiJ9l2NOs6SKRtm1bdtVyRMMI0pIA)

**`Builder`** - iterates through only one property `__childProps__` while `Level` tuple length less than original tuple `ObjTuple`. IF length is equal - return `Result` merged with `ObjProps`, otherwise: merge `prop` from tuple by index `Tuple[Level['length']]` with recursive iteration through  `__childProps__`.

As you might have noticed, I increase `Level` tuple each time by `1`.